# How does default redirect URL work in Spring Security 5?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have gone through below posts. Still I am unable to understand redirection URI concept.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2login-advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-redirection-endpoint

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2login-sample-redirect-uri

In identity server , we get our client application registered and for code grant type, we tell that this would be our redirect URL i.e. `https://someserver:port/`

However, spring and other post suggests that to set redirect URI as `{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}`.

I am confused if i have set redirect URI as `https://someserver:port/` in identity server , how `{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}` i.e. `https://someserver:port/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}` will work.

Should it not give invalid redirect URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "redirectUrl" parameter is to protect the exchange of an authorization code with an access token so that it's performed by a service available at one of the URLs approved for redirect.

If you use `https://someserver:port/*`, then it will match all endpoints on that server. When relying on the default Spring Security endpoint `{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}`, it's better to be specific in the redirect URL configuration and use `https://someserver:port/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}` as the value. Both options work correctly, but the latter is more secure.

Comment: Where does the value for `baseUrl` come from?  From my research it appears to be the `Host` header but I can't be sure.